# Sending an email from my virtual box

Tags: email, localhost, send, virtualbox

I do web development from my ubuntu server, ubuntu is running in virtualbox in my  windows 7. What do I need to configure inside of ubuntu in order to send email to any public domain, gmail.com for example? I need this set up for testing email templates etc... Thanks, Jaro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing email on the ubuntu machine, the best way is to create a local account and use email like account@localhost.
It is not a good test otherwise if you want to send mail directly from your system, as many ISPs are not allowing SMTP traffic over broadband DSL, e.g. my provider THREE in UK doesnt allow it, as well many big email companies will reject emails coming from broadband subnets.
Another way would be deploying the mail server, which is complex, also you can test your app at any free hosting provider too.
Basically testing email is nothing  close to being simple and to test it properly, you need a production system with mail fully setup and working, whitelisted, not on DSL and so on.

Comment: Rackspace has on-demand cloud server, where you can setup full mail server with reverse DNS instantly, with no problems, as their ranges are clear and they dont block SMTP. The cost is really low, for 1 day test it costs like 25p.

Comment: Thanks quick reply. My company has a running production mail server. So is there any way how to configure localhost's mail service to use this one? I can send emails from my testing site but need to commit a code, deploy it, run a test and see result. That's to much effort :)

Comment: Depends on which MTA you use. Postfix has this "satellite system" option in the set-up which is basically a canned configuration for your scenario.

Comment: Can you send me a link to some documentation? This mail stuff is little bit confusing.Thank you.

Comment: Hi. On your production mail server, you can setup mailbox for your  app like shopsupport@company.com and configure this account in your mailng class, like PHP Mailer, where you put your MTA ip number, email address, login and password for SMTP authentication. This way it should be working fine as for the website.

Comment: However if you can, you can use cloud email server if you have really lots of emails. For a busy website it's best to have such email system separately, and to setup something like this on Linux is easy with e.g. CPanel, Virtualmin etc.